# Use arrow keys to browse history commands of gdb on Eclipse's Debugger Console

Tags: eclipse, debugging

E.g: When I press "UP" key on Debugger console, I'd like to select the last command sent to gdb, and not to move the cursor:

[image]

How do I change this? On windows command prompt it behaves as I want but not on MingW64 or Eclipse's Debugger Window.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching around for these features, unfortunately it looks like they are available in Linux only. See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Archive/FullGDBConsole and this related sighting comment which mentions why it doesn't work for windows: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303808#c7

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, [see "Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)